# Remove folder synchronized with tortoise svn

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have synchronized a folder with folder in tortoise svn. Now I want to synchronize this folder with another folder in tortoise svn. How to do this. Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

The mechanism in Subversion are a little bit different. You speak here from a checkout, if you work on a local copy. There are two cases here:

You want to work on a different part of the repository:

1. Checkout that part at a new location locally (so you are able to work in parallel on both).
2. Switch your current location to the new part of the repository. This will replace all files locally, and you are no longer able to work on both parts in parallel.

The first scenario is normally used. There are some cases where it may be not appropriate:

- You have not enough place locally. You should change that first, because you are not able to  work anyway.
- You are working on a branch, and want to merge some of the changes on the branch on the trunk or another branch. Then a `svn switch` is the normal way to do that.

Alternatively, you may do a [sparse checkout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html) of the common parent of the two folders, and populate only the parts you are interested in.